# "One property may be said to include another if the first is necessarily such that anything that has it also has the second."

Tags: epistemology, interpretation

Here is a sentence from philosophical work written by Roderick Chisholm Theory of knowledge. Which i failed to translate and understand. Explain it please in simple words.

> One property may be said to include another if the first is necessarily such that anything that has it also has the second.

Comment: You mean like "All men are mortal?" So the quality of being a man includes the property of being mortal. Because if something is a man then that thing is mortal. This reverses the usual convention that the set includes the subset. If every element of A is an element of B, we say that A is a subset of B or *B includes A*. Your quote has the "include" relationship the other way 'round.

Comment: Can you give us the reference (page #)? Also when you say "translate" do you mean state in formal logic or render in a different human language or make comprehensible in English?

Comment: @virmaior page #19. By translate i meant as you said "human language", on russian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe an example will help you: redness is such that necessarily, anything that is red is also colourful. So redness contains colourfulness.
Necessarily means that you cannot conceive of something having the first without also having the second.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will use this as a note for a translation. As an explanation example. I used to think in that way too, when one property contains many. I asked this because words order here is seems alogical for me. Also i confused by unusual using of words as for non-philosopher.

Answer (score 1):

Let ϕ and ψ be properties, let x stand for a thing.

ϕ includes ψ means, for any x, ϕ(x) implies ψ(x).

**Edit: This appears to be defined backward!!!**

Let A = {x:ϕx}, B = {x:ψx}

(∀x) ϕ(x) ⇒ ψ(x) implies (∀x) x ∈ A ⇒ x ∈ B  implies A ⊂ B, Which means A is contained by B!

Comment: @user71305: This is odd. A property is equivalent to a set; a term having a property is equivalent to belonging to a set. Let A = {x:ϕ(x)}, B ={x:ψ(x)}, then ϕ(x) implies ψ(x) means ∀x, x ∈ A implies x ∈ B, which in turn implies A is included by B. This is exactly the opposite of the above definition!

Comment: @user71305 When speaking of intension, we use imply; when speaking of extension, we use include. This book has shown signs of muddle-headedness.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, strictly speaking because the necessity was droped and only extensions are considered.

Comment: I don't think it's muddle-headed, it's just a specific vocabulary suited for metaphysics rather than logic: a property is said to include the other if it implies it necessarily (=in every possible world).

Comment: @quen_tin - OK. He's probably building his own system. He **can** define it that way, but he is more likely to sow the seed of confusion.

Comment: @quen_tin - It is odd. That's probably why the OP asked it in the first place.

Comment: It's a bit odd indeed that it's exactly the reverse relation for extensions, but maybe it makes sense if we think in terms of meaning or comprehension of properties: the property of being red includes as one of its aspects the property of being colourful.

Comment: @GeorgeChen - there is no error. If we consider "for all x (if P(x), then Q(x))" and read it *extensionally*, we consider P and Q as "extension" of two sets P and Q; thus, it is correct to say that P is included into Q. But "traditional logic" consider also *intensions* (i.e. concepts). Consider now the property of "beeing a square"; a square is a quadrilateral with some more "specifications"; thus, from an intensional point of view, the property or characteristic of "being a quadrilateral" is contained into that of "being a square".

Comment: @Mauro - Good to know. Here's a curious fact: PM's "imply" symbol is "⊃" which is "include" in set theory, and, for set operations, PM has only "is contained by" symbol (⊂ ), but has no symbol for "include." W&R are very clever in taking advantage of people's habits.

Comment: That was why I was incredulous when I realized PM's particular way of naming domain and converse domain.

Comment: @GeorgeChen - from [Britannica](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/289860/intension-and-extension) : "**intension and extension**,  in logic, correlative words that indicate the reference of a term or concept: “intension” indicates the internal content of a term or concept that constitutes its formal definition; and “extension” indicates its range of applicability by naming the particular objects that it denotes." 1/2

Comment: From Antoine Arnauld & Pierre Nicole, *Logic or the Art of Thinking*, Ch.6 : "I call the *comprehension* [i.e. intension] of an idea the attributes that it contains in itself, and that cannot be removed wjthout destroying the idea. For example, the comprehension of the idea of a triangle contains extension, shape, three lines, three angles, and the equality of these three angles to two right angles, etc." Thus "all triangles are three-lined objects" has the form: "for all x (if P(x), then Q(x))" but the "three-lined" attribute is contained into the "triangle" idea. 2/2